# Automatic Cell Update on Certain Date

Tags: google-sheets

I am quite new to Google Sheets and I am wondering if someone can help me as I am looking to update a cell by +1 each time a certain date comes about.

***I currently have;***

- =today cell
- Counter cell (This will be the one rising by +1 each time the =today hits a certain day of the month)
- A monthly cost cell which I will subtract from a total cell
- A total cell which should decrease by the monthly cost each time the counter rises.

I already have a setup where If I manually add 1 to the counter cell then the total cell decreases as I want it but is there an automatic way by using the date? Say if the =today turns the 25th and a cell is assigned to the 25th then the counter goes up automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055612

`=datedif(G27,today(),"M")` where G27 is your reference date, could also be a quoted string for the first date "04/16/2018"

that will provide you the number of months since the reference month, your "counter cell". Datedif for months only increments the month based on the numbered day of the month (ie the above will not say 1 until 05/16/2018. See "Notes" in the above link) which matches what you described.